# Ulogd2 cannot find PCAP plugin?

Tags: iptables

I am trying to log the packet data from iptables with Ulogd2. So I wish to dump it to pcap file. But it does not seem to work.

This error in syslog is:

```
Apr 15 14:58:05 shiskey-HP-EliteBook-8470p ulogd[31692]: tok=`log2:NFLOG'
Apr 15 14:58:05 shiskey-HP-EliteBook-8470p ulogd[31692]: pushing `NFLOG' on stack
Apr 15 14:58:05 shiskey-HP-EliteBook-8470p ulogd[31692]: tok=`base1:BASE'
Apr 15 14:58:05 shiskey-HP-EliteBook-8470p ulogd[31692]: pushing `BASE' on stack
Apr 15 14:58:05 shiskey-HP-EliteBook-8470p ulogd[31692]: tok=`pcap1:PCAP'
Apr 15 14:58:05 shiskey-HP-EliteBook-8470p ulogd[31692]: can't find requested plugin PCAP
Apr 15 14:58:05 shiskey-HP-EliteBook-8470p ulogd[31692]: Changing UID / GID
Apr 15 14:58:05 shiskey-HP-EliteBook-8470p ulogd[31692]: initialization finished, entering main loop
```

It says "Cannot find PCAP plugin". I checked the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ulogd/ulogd/` folder and funnily enough, ulogd_output_PCAP.so was missing. So I googled a little and downloaded the latest version [from this site](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=ulogd_output_PCAP.so()(64bit)), pasted the file in the above folder and restarted Ulogd2 service. But it is still the same error!

My Ulogd verison is 2.0.5 (Ubuntu repository). Does is not support pcap anymore? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working!

The issue was that I was trying to use a non-compatible pcap plugin. There is in fact the right plugin available in Ubuntu repository for me to install. I wish I checked this before :smh:

So my solution (after deleting the downloaded ulogd_output_PCAP.so file):

```
sudo apt install ulogd2-pcap
```

It is working as expected now.